# How can I pass a numeric variable to regular expression in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function which validates a password.

```
CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]{2,}/, {
              hasCapitalCase: true
 }),
```

right now it is hard coded to 2 upper Case letters but I would like to load the password requirments based on a user profile via variables in my case it would be **this.paswdProfile.upperCase** but if I replace the 2 with the variable it no longer works.
Here is my CustomValidator Code

```
export class CustomValidators {
static patternValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
  if (!control.value) {
    // if control is empty return no error
    return null;
  }

  // test the value of the control against the regexp supplied
  const valid = regex.test(control.value);

  // if true, return no error (no error), else return error passed in the second parameter
  return valid ? null : error;
};
}
```

here is how i use it

```
paswdProfile = {minChar: 10, numbers: 2, upperCase: 4, lowerCase: 3, specialChar: 2}

 CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]{ paswdProfile.upperCase ,}/, {
              hasCapitalCase: true
            }),
```

i know that i can access the value because in my template i print

> Must contain at least {{ paswdProfile.upperCase }} in Capital Case!

and that shows correct value

Comment: when you arre going to update the number , and how you get the value of this.paswdProfile.upperCase

Comment: can you share the formgroup code and put the code with point wherer it start not working

Comment: for now i use just some static nbrs like this paswdProfile = {minChar: 10, numbers: 2, upperCase: 4, lowerCase: 3, specialChar: 2}

Comment: is it working when u have static values?

Comment: when i use CustomValidators.patternValidator(new RegExp(`[A-Z]{ 4 ,}`), { it doesnt work either

Comment: try Validators.minLength(4) and regex without length

Comment: You current regex say that you need to have two uppercase letters adjacent to each other e.g. AA is match but AaA does not match. Is it right behavior or due you want to count the number of uppercase letters in total string?

Comment: Ideally I want AA and AaA be a valid match

Comment: can you try with this.
`const valid = regex.test(control.value);` replace with `new RegExp(regex).test(control.value)`;

Answer (score 2):

you can create a regex pattern to test number of lower case , upper with spical characters but this will consider as a pattern and it's hard for the user to know that he must enter 4 of more lower or upper and I 'm not expert regex  so my idea is to create a validation funtion test the value and base of the test I will give to the user different validation messages.

```js
interface PasswordProfile {
  upperCase: number;
  lowerCase: number;
  numbers: number;
  minChar: number;
  specialChar: number;
}
export class CustomValidators {
  static passwordValidator(passwordProfile: PasswordProfile): ValidatorFn {

    function patternTest(value, pattern: RegExp): string[] {
      return (value.match(pattern) || []).length;
    }

    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      if (!control.value) {
        return null;
      }
      const value: string = control.value;

      if ((value.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length < passwordProfile.upperCase) {
        return {
          passwordStrength: {
            message: `the password must containe ${
              passwordProfile.upperCase
            } upper case`
          }
        };
      }

      if (patternTest(value, /[a-z]/g).length < passwordProfile.lowerCase) {
        return {
          passwordStrength: {
            message: `the password must containe ${
              passwordProfile.lowerCase
            } lowercase case`
          }
        };
      }

      if (patternTest(value, /[0-9]/g).length < passwordProfile.numbers) {
        return {
          passwordStrength: {
            message: `the password must containe ${
              passwordProfile.numbers
            } numbers`
          }
        };
      }

      if (
        patternTest(value, /[!@#\$%\^&]/g).length < passwordProfile.specialChar
      ) {
        return {
          passwordStrength: {
            message: `the password must containe ${
              passwordProfile.specialChar
            } specialChar`
          }
        };
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-message-nhurmx)

Answer (score 1):

Based om Muhammed's answer i was able to come up wit a bit more flexible solution. This way the patternValidator just checks how often the pattern is matched and if the number is equal or bigger then the number in required password profile. Also with leaving all the validation patterns in the Form Group its cleaner and more flexible as well.

```
  static patternValidator(regex: RegExp, requiredTimes: number, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      if (!control.value) {
        // if control is empty return no error
        return null;
      }
      const value: string = control.value;
       // test the value of the control against the regexp supplied
      const valid =  ((value.match(regex) || []).length >= requiredTimes)
      // if true, return no error (no error), else return error passed in the second parameter
      return valid ? null : error;
    };
  } 

    newPassword: [
      null,
      Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        // check whether the entered password has a number
        CustomValidators.patternValidator(/\d/g, this.paswdProfile.numbers , {
          hasNumber: true
        }),
        // check whether the entered password has upper case letter
        CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]/g, this.paswdProfile.uperCase, {
          hasCapitalCase: true
        }),
        // check whether the entered password has a lower case letter
        CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[a-z]/g, this.paswdProfile.lowerCase,  {
          hasSmallCase: true
        }),
        // check whether the entered password has a special character
        CustomValidators.patternValidator(
          /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g, this.paswdProfile.specialChar ,
          {
            hasSpecialCharacters: true
          }
        ),
        Validators.minLength(this.paswdProfile.minChar)
      ])
    ],
```